# Grouping data by month and year based on a count()

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table structure as follows:

Shops Table:

| id | shop_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My Shop |
| 2 | Another Shop |
| 3 | Final Shop |

Orders Table:

| shop_id | order_id | data | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | json | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | 456 | json | 01/01/2023 |
| 3 | 234 | json | 02/02/2023 |
| 1 | 765 | json | 03/02/2023 |
| 2 | 435 | json | 04/03/2023 |
| 3 | 788 | json | 04/03/2023 |

From these 2 tables, I would like to select the shops name, ID and the count of its orders grouped by the month they were created, something like:

| shop_id | shop_name | order_count_january_23 | order_count_february_23 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My Shop | 1 | 2 | ... |
| 2 | Another Shop | 12 | 45 | ... |
| 3 | Final Shop | 8 | 36 | ... |

I have tried grouping the number of orders but i can't seem to be able to get the exact output I need, I've also tried using sub-queries but to no avail.

```sql
SELECT orders.id,
       shops.name,
       count(orders.id) as 'Orders',
       MONTH(orders.created_at) as Month,
       YEAR(orders.created_at) as Year
FROM orders
JOIN shops on shops.id = orders.id
GROUP BY orders.wholesaler_id, Year, Month
```

I know the above does not work however this is where I became stumped. It does however, give me a list of shops with there order numbers but this is not in the correct format

Any help is massivley appreciated.

Comment: The result should only be for the current or previous year or for the last 6 / 12 months. Or for all entries in the table

Comment: For all entries in the table is what i am looking for

Comment: If there are records for 90 different months, do you want 90 columns?

Comment: Thats correct, I have a lot of data in the tables

Comment: Does **[this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdTXJGT3CCb2RT19gVgTTv/0)** help?

Comment: @mandy8055, the OP wants N number of columns

Comment: @Asgar I believe OP mentioned he's fine with it. He can write the condition for the dates. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. The one which I provided is one way to go

Comment: I would prefer to have N number of columns so as to not have to update my query a lot if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FOR MYSQL**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @columns = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
        'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = ', MONTH, 
        ' AND YEAR = ', YEAR, 
        ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_count_', 
        MONTHNAME, '_', YEAR
    )
    SEPARATOR ', '
) INTO @columns
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(created_at) AS MONTH, YEAR(created_at) AS YEAR, 
           MONTHNAME(created_at) AS MONTHNAME
    FROM Orders
) AS months;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
                    s.ID AS shop_id,
                    s.shop_name,
                    ', @columns, '
                  FROM
                    shops s
                  LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT shop_id, 
                             MONTH(created_at) AS MONTH, 
                             YEAR(created_at) AS YEAR
                      FROM orders
                      GROUP BY shop_id, MONTH(created_at), YEAR(created_at)
                  ) o ON s.ID = o.shop_id
                  GROUP BY
                    s.ID, s.shop_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**FOR MSSQL**

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Generate a comma-separated list of aggregated expressions for each month and year
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ', '') +
                 'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), MONTH) + 
                 ' AND YEAR = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR) + 
                 ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_count_' + MONTHNAME + '_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCt MONTH(created_at) AS MONTH, YEAR(created_at) AS YEAR, FORMAT(created_at, 'MMMM') AS MONTHNAME
  FROM Orders
) AS months;

-- Construct the dynamic SQL query
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
                    s.id AS shop_id,
                    s.shop_name,
                    ', @columns, '
                  FROM
                    Shops s
                  LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT shop_id, 
                             MONTH(created_at) AS MONTH, 
                             YEAR(created_at) AS YEAR
                      FROM Orders
                      GROUP BY shop_id, MONTH(created_at), YEAR(created_at)
                  ) o ON s.id = o.shop_id
                  GROUP BY
                    s.id, s.shop_name');

-- Execute the dynamic SQL query
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Would this run in MySQL, i've tried to run the above in DataGrip however it seems to be throwing errors based on the `DECLARE` statement

Comment: wait give me 5 minutes. I thought you need query in MSSQL

Comment: Yes josh, I have updated my response with MySQL Syntax also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNT` with `IF`, like so:

```
SELECT
       orders.order_id,
       shops.shop_name,
       COUNT(IF(
              MONTH(orders.created_at) = 1 AND YEAR(orders.created_at) = 2023,
              1,
              NULL
       )) AS order_count_january_23,
FROM orders
JOIN shops ON shops.id = orders.id
GROUP BY orders.order_id, shops.shop_name
```

Comment: Would this mean that i would have to add a new `if` statement for each month that elapses?

Comment: In some SQL dialects (e.g. GoogleSQL) you can use the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement and  `STRING_AGG` function for automated generation of columns. I'm not that familiar with MySQL, so I'm not sure how it'd go in this case.